# SQL Data Import From Text Inserts All Fields into Single Column

Tags: sql-server, import, ssms, flat-file

I have a txt file and the data looks like this

[value]~*[value]~*[value]~*[value]~*

When I try to use the SSMS import wizard to import into SQL Server, everything is put into one column and the ~* characters are included in the values (see image)
[data in single column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N2t2l.png)

I suspect it is a delimiter/encoding problem but I haven't found a way to sort it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your delimiter. When defining your Flat File Source, on the Columns Pane, enter the delimiter in the "Column delimiter" drop down. For my test file was the `=`. Then click "Refresh".

[image]

Comment: Wow, so simple thank you. I thought you had to select from the drop down menu I didn't realize you could type free form